# Derivation for relationship between rest mass, kinetic energy and momentum

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass, momentum

I am trying to find a particle's rest mass in terms of its kinetic energy and momentum. Is this following derivation correct?

$(E_{0}+K)^2=E_{0}^2+(pc)^2$

$2E_{0}K=p^2c^2-K^2$

$2m_{0}c^2K=p^2c^2-K^2$

$m_{0}=\frac{p^2c^2-K^2}{2c^2K}$

The reason I am confused is the correct equation does not have the $c^2$ terms. Where have I gone wrong?

**EDIT**

I am using this to solve the following question:

If a particle has kinetic energy $K = 50 MeV$ when its momentum magnitude $p = 130 MeV/c$, what is the ratio $m/m_{e}$ of its mass to the electron mass?

Comment: Are you sure that the "correct" equation was not derived using units in which $c=1$?  In SI units, the factors of $c^2$ are necessary for the equation to be dimensionally correct.

Comment: Would you please be able to explain how the units affect this derivation using the question I added? Thanks so much. It seems that the equation I used doesn't work when using either $eVs$ or $J$

Comment: $m_0/m_e=\frac{p^2c^2-K^2}{2(m_ec^2)K}$. The units of the numerator and denominator are both MeV$^2$.

Comment: If I say $m_{e}=9.1*10^{-31}$, $K=50*10^6*1.602*10^{-19}$ and $p=130*10^6*1.602*10^{-19}$, I get $m_{0}/m_{e}=2.98*10^{19}$ when the actual answer is $282.35$ (they stay in eV and don't use the $c^2$ terms). What am I doing wrong? How do I use this formula with $J$?

Comment: Work in MeV, the units specified, for simplicity. There is no reason to convert to joules. And put the $c$ in. You’re off by the factor of $c^2$.

Comment: When you don’t put the $c$ in, you have to think in units where mass is energy. For example, you just use $m_e=0.511$ MeV.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it made sense once I started including units in my calculations as I could see how they cancelled etc.